# Troubleshooting Canon scanner over network

Tags: networking, drivers, canon, scanner

I have a Canon MG6851 and running Ubuntu 14.04. And i cannot get the scanner to work over wifi. I tried `SANE` and `scangearmp2`. In theory i installed all Canon drivers and i did manage to set up the printer over wifi. But i cannot figure out to scan over wifi.

I know there might not be an out of the box solution but i would love to troubleshoot. I just don't know where to start. So some background:

For `SANE` i know, that my scanner is not in the list of supported devices, so that might be the problem in the first place ;) Although that is also mentioned that `bjnp` Protocol is supported, so i tried to add my scanners ip to `sane.d/pixma.conf`. No luck. Running `scanImage -L -v` prints:

```
[pixma] udp_command: No data received (select): timed out
[pixma] udp_command: No data received (select): timed out
[pixma] udp_command: No data received (select): timed out
[pixma] Cannot read scanner make & model: _]����
```

I am guessing here that it is trying to send a `udp` packet to the printer via `bjnp://[ip-address]` as noted in `pixma.conf` trice. And that is not working (i can however `ping` the ip-address). Might it be my printer not responding to `bjnp` or some misconfiguration of `udp` on the firewall? Can i test those isolated?

Anyway, i thought `scangearmp2` would be able to achieve the wifi scanning as well? But the scanner was not detected. So can i troubleshoot the issue somehow (after all it might still work on `SANE`, so knowing the exact problem would help)?

P.S: I can scan over USB, so i thought i might be able to get scanning over wifi to work as well with some tweaking.

Comment: so for ScanGear I guess you went somewhere like here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100690502.html to download scangearmp2-3.20-1-deb.tar.gz and you run it from a terminal with `scangearmp2` .. with the install script, it is surprising it did not set it up for you; do you have a firewall? some suggest dropping it to see if scanning works; then attempt to put back in place; I see the pixma.conf file gives as an example "bjnp://myscanner.my.domain:8612" and says "method must be bjnp"

Comment: There has long been a command `cnijnetprn --search auto` that I found on searching around: does it give you a return? a link such as this http://linux.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_Canon_PIXMA_to_work_on_Linux suggests you should get something like "networkcnijnet:/00-1E-8F-67-4C-D8 “Canon MP6850 series” “Canon-MG6850-series_00-1E-8F-67-4C-D8″" if it is being seen

Comment: Thank you for your input. You are right regarding `ScanGear`. I would not say it did not set it up, as it works for a wired connection, so it must have been successful somehow. I have no active firewall, and i was able to send `udp` packets to the printer with `netcat`.  As far as the `cnijnetprn` is concerned: the repository mentioned is quite inactive for a long time and does not seem to support my printer model. Furthermore the printer works over wifi. So i was looking more into a solution of debugging the connection process as this obviously fails in `scangearmp2`.

Comment: do any of the ubuntu tutorials help? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial?action=show&redirect=sane.d+tutorial and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo and I often think the Arch wikis are very good https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SANE